# Two sets have the same cardinal proof

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Suppose that $S, T$ are sets such that $S$ is infinite and $T = \{t_i: i = 1, ..., n\}$ with $T$ having $n \geq 1$ distinct elements. If $S \cap T = \{\}$, show that $card(S) = card(S \cup T)$.

Hint: Construct a bijective function $\phi: S \rightarrow S \cup T$.

I tried defining various functions but cannot seem to construct one that satisfies the requirements above. I would appreciate if someone could provide such a bijective function.

Comment: What's your definition of a set being infinite?

Comment: @GitGud A set $S$ is finite if $S = \{s_1, ..., s_n\}$ (ie has a cardinal $n$) or $S = \{\}$. So, by negation, the definition of infinite is clear.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is infinite then there exists $C\subset S$ such that $C$ is countable infinite.

Therefore $C=\{c_1,c_2,...\}$. Now, consider $\phi(z)=z$ for $z\notin C$, $\phi(c_k)=t_k$ for $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ and finally $\phi(c_{n+k})=c_{k}$ for $k\geq 1$.

This function is surjective because $\phi(S\setminus C)=S\setminus C$, $\phi(\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n\})=\{t_1,t_2,...,t_n\}$ and finally $\phi(\{c_{n+1},c_{n+2},...\})=\{c_1,c_2,...\}=C$.

Let $a,b\in S$. If both are in $C$ then we have $\phi(a)=\phi(b)\Rightarrow a=b$. If $a\in C$ and $b\notin C$ then their image can not be equal because $\phi(a)\in C\cup T$ and $\phi(b)\in S\setminus C$ and $(C\cup T) \cap (S\setminus C)=\emptyset$.

We are left to prove that if $a,b\in C$ then $\phi(a)=\phi(b)\Rightarrow a=b$. Let $a=c_r$ and $b=c_s$ and consider $r<s$ without loss of generality.

If $s\leq n$ then $\phi(a)=\phi(b)\iff\phi(c_r)=\phi(c_s) \iff t_r=t_s$and so they are indeed different.

If $r\geq n+1$ then $\phi(a)=\phi(b)\iff\phi(c_r)=\phi(c_s) \iff c_{r-n}=c_{s-n}$ and so they are indeed different.

If $r\leq n< s$ then $\phi(a)=t_r$ and $\phi(b)=c_{s-n}$ which are different.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I can't seem to show a bijection here probably because of the piecewise nature of the function...

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you check that $\phi$ is one-to-one?

Comment: Here's my attempt: (Case 1) Assume $\phi(c_1) = \phi(c_2)$ for $c_1, c_2 \in S$. Then,  if $c_1, c_2 \notin C$, then clearly, $\phi(c_1) = \phi(c_2) \implies c_1 = c_2$/ (Case 2) Assume again that $\phi(c_1) = \phi(c_2)$. Then $\phi(c_1) = b_1$ and $\phi(c_2) = b_2$. So, $b_1 = b_2$ (but how do we show that $c_1 = c_2$ from this?). (Case 3) Assume $\phi(c_{n+1}) = \phi(c_{n+2})$ for $c_{n+1}, c_{n+2} \in S$. Then, $\phi(c_{n+1}) = c_1$ and $\phi(c_{n+2}) = c_2$ (Again, how do we show that $c_{n+1} = c_{n+2}$?). I'm a little confused.

Comment: Check my answer again, I proved the function is one-to-one.

Comment: Ah! I see. Out of curiosity, where does the fact that $S \cap T$ is empty come in?

Comment: You wrote it as a hipothesis in beginning.

Comment: Sorry, one last question: For the step where $a, b \in C$, how can $r = s$ if we are considering the case when $r < s$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120116/discussion-between-gio-and-kraftsman).

Answer (score 1):

$S$ is of infinite cardinal, i.e.
$$ |S| \geq \aleph_0 $$
We define $\varphi : S \to S \sqcup T$ as it follows:

for $1\leq i \leq n$, there exits $s_i^0\in S$ s.t. $\varphi(s_i^0) = t_i$

recursively we define, for $1\leq i \leq n$, $s_i^{k+1} \in S\setminus \cup_{l=0}^k \{s_1^l, \cdots, s_n^l\}$, s.t. $\varphi(s_i^{k+1}) = s_i^{k}$

We put $S' = \cup_{k\geq 0}\{s_1^k,\cdots, s_n^k\}$, and for $s\notin S'$,
we define $\varphi(s) = s$

Comment: I tried this but I can't seem to show the bijection